# user agent of iPhone doesn't contain iPhone string

Tags: iphone, agent

To ensure users use iPhones to access web application, I check user agent in the http request. Some times I found there is no iPhone string in it .  the caught user agent is
*mozilla/5.0 (macintosh; intel mac os x 10_15_6) applewebkit/605.1.15 (khtml, like gecko) version/14.0 safari/605.1.15*
the tag is macintosh not iPhone. As I know , macintosh represent a computer not a mobile.

But the user told me he used iPhone to access system. Did he use a fake iPhone mobile ?

Comment: Could be using the iOS simulator

Comment: @EmilioPelaez Thank you for comments. I confirmed with the user that he didn't use simulator. Actually, he has no idea about simulator.